# Как программно задать привязки к границам экрана при повороте (iOS)?

Tags: xcode, ios

Если создаю кнопку через `Interface Builder`, то в настройках `Size inspector` могу задать необходимые привязки положения и размеров кнопки при повороте. 
Но как быть, если кнопка создана программно в коде, и в `interface builder` ее само собой нет. Как в этом случае можно задать привязку к левой нижней границе экрана?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У все потомков `UIView` есть свойство `autoresizingMask`.  Чтобы установить в него несколько значений, используйте `+`.

updated: Лучше все же использовать битовую операцию ИЛИ (`|`) вместо `+`.

Comment: Наверное всё же не `+`, а `|` (логическое или).

Comment: Я имел в виду не логическое ИЛИ, извините, а [побитовое](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Битовые_операции#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.98.D0.9B.D0.98_.28OR.29).

Comment: Да, вы правы. Apple советует использовать битовое "или".  Но тем не менее + почему-то тоже работает... Но лучше все же | использовать.

Answer (score 1):

В методе - `(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`
`(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;` отловить сообщение об изменении интерфейса и задать ей (кнопке) новый фрэйм, в зависимости от ориентации девайса.